# picturebox memory overflow when display is turned off

Tags: vb.net, out-of-memory, picturebox

I have created a VB.NET forms application that loads a new picture into a picturebox every tick event.  However, when my computer's display turns off, the exe's memory usage slowly climbs up.  If I move the mouse after a short time and the screen turns on, the memory suddenly drops back to normal.  However if I leave the screen turned off, the memory usage continues to climb and eventually cause a out of memory exception.  Also the picturebox image becomes a big red X.

How do I detect the screen turning off? - done

How do I get the POWERBROADCAST_SETTING structure (lParam) data out of msg?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373247.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372723.aspx

```
Declare Function RegisterPowerSettingNotification Lib "user32" (ByVal hRecipient As IntPtr, ByRef PowerSettingGuid As Guid, ByVal Flags As Int32) As IntPtr

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim GG As System.Guid
    System.Guid.TryParse("02731015-4510-4526-99e6-e5a17ebd1aea", GG)
    RegisterPowerSettingNotification(Me.Handle, GG, 0)
    '...
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    'MessageBox.Show(msg.Msg)
    If msg.WParam = &H8013 Then
        Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString)
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(msg)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'code to load some image using PictureBox1.Load()
End Sub
```

Console outputs:
msg=0x218 (WM_POWERBROADCAST) hwnd=0x9108a wparam=0x8013 lparam=0x57f5080 result=0x0
msg=0x218 (WM_POWERBROADCAST) hwnd=0x9108a wparam=0x8013 lparam=0x57f50e0 result=0x0
msg=0x218 (WM_POWERBROADCAST) hwnd=0x9108a wparam=0x8013 lparam=0x57f4d20 result=0x0
msg=0x218 (WM_POWERBROADCAST) hwnd=0x9108a wparam=0x8013 lparam=0x57f5020 result=0x0
msg=0x218 (WM_POWERBROADCAST) hwnd=0x9108a wparam=0x8013 lparam=0x57f4d60 result=0x0
msg=0x218 (WM_POWERBROADCAST) hwnd=0x9108a wparam=0x8013 lparam=0x57f5180 result=0x0

Sorry about the formatting...just joined this site.

**edit:**
This seems to work.

```
Public Structure PB_S
    Public PowerSetting As Guid
    Public DataLength As UInteger  'dword (32-bit unsigned int)
    Public Data As Byte 'uchar
End Structure
Dim P_inst As PB_S

P_inst = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(msg.LParam, GetType(PB_S)), PB_S)
```

Console printing out the stuff in P_inst:

msg=0x218 (WM_POWERBROADCAST) hwnd=0x14a10fe wparam=0x8013 lparam=0x295048 result=0x0
0
4
02731015-4510-4526-99e6-e5a17ebd1aea

msg=0x218 (WM_POWERBROADCAST) hwnd=0x14a10fe wparam=0x8013 lparam=0x295048 result=0x0
1
4
02731015-4510-4526-99e6-e5a17ebd1aea

Answer (score 0):

To detect if the computer is locked, screensaver, or sleep, see the post here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?228575-resolved-Detect-Screen-Saver-Sleep-Mode-Computer-locked&p=1348493&viewfull=1#post1348493. The code is for VB6, but it should work for VB.Net (with a few modifications) too. If it doesn't work, simply comment on this post.